# Collection of $n - 1$ bijections on the set of $n$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $\sigma_1, \ldots \sigma_{n-1} \in S_n \setminus \{\operatorname{id}\}$. Does there exists $k \in \{1,2, \ldots n\}$ such that $k \sigma_1  \ne k \sigma_2 \ne  \cdots \ne k \sigma_{n-1}$?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by multiplying a number with a permutation?

Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: $k\sigma$ means image of $k \in \{1,2,\ldots n\}$ under $\sigma \in S_n$.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried?

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit?  $\operatorname{id}$ is the usual correct "spelling" for the identity function while $id$ rather looks like $i \cdot d$.

Comment: It exists and is quite simple. It exists actually $n$ different permutations that satisfy that for $n\geq 3$

Comment: @PenasRaul...what will be that $k \in \{1,2, \ldots,n\}$?

Comment: @Snufsan.. I have seen it for n = 3, 4. I was getting it. I wanted to see it in general.

Comment: @JitenderKumar: Your answer to me seems to have no connection to what I asked...

Comment: @Frunobulax: I have put brackets on id because of setminus notation.

Comment: @JitenderKumar: That's what I had already done.  But I also added something else which you removed.  I'll do it again.

Comment: @Frunobulax..Acually that reply I have written for Snufsan...by mistake I put it in your blog.

Comment: @Frunobulax...ok....do it please

Comment: @Frunobulax: what about the question which I have posed it here?

Comment: @Frunobulax....Thanks...

Comment: @JitenderKumar: I think I have no obligation to answer it...

Comment: Do you mean the $k\sigma_i$ are distinct? Or do you really mean that $k\sigma_i\neq k\sigma_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$?

Comment: I mean the $k\sigma_i$ are distinct for $1 \le i \le n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG we may take $k=1$. Suppose you take $\sigma_i(1)=i$. Can you do that and still have all the permutations distinct? If $n\ge3$ you could take $\sigma_i$ to be obtained by cycling $\sigma_{i-1}$ That way you get $n$ permutations, all distinct with the required property.

That leaves $n<3$. I think you can figure those out!

[Added later. Sorry, that was not clear.] The idea is to make sure that the columns are permutations as well as the rows if we put the results of $\sigma_i$ in successive rows. It may help if I give an example for $n=4$:

$\begin{array}{c|cccc} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ \hline \sigma_1 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 2\\ \sigma_2 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 4\\ \sigma_3 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3\\ \sigma_4 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1\end{array}$

Of course, the last row is a bonus, since you only asked for $n-1$.

Comment: If I say $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_{n-1}$ are arbitrary $n-1$ elements in $S_n \setminus \{\operatorname{id}\}$. Then what you say?

Comment: If $\sigma_1 = (1 \; 2)$, $\sigma_2 = (1 \; 2)(3 \; 4)$, $\sigma_3 = (3 \; 4)$ in $S_4$. There is no such $k$ with the above property.